# Quel article devant les noms pluriels qui définissent une catégorie ?

Tags: articles

Je dois admettre que je suis toujours troublé par l'usage des articles définis et indéfinis en français. J'ai vu un nouveau cas ce matin où je n'ai pas compris pourquoi un article défini a été utilisé dans la première phrase et un article indéfini a été utilisé dans la deuxième.

> Vous regardez beaucoup d'émissions à la télévision ?
>
> Non, je ne regarde que **les** films.
>
> Et tu lis beaucoup ?
>
> Non, je ne lis que **des** romans.

Moi, je pense qu'un article indéfini devrait avoir été utilisé dans les deux phrases. Pourquoi a-t-il dit « **les** films » si ceux-ci ne sont pas spécifiés dans le contexte ? Je pense que ces deux cas (c'est-à-dire, romans et films) sont exactement la même chose donc pourquoi a-t-il changé les articles ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les deux possibilités que tu présentes sont valides et employées. La version avec l'article indéfini est le cas normal, le plus classique, mais celle qui te gêne est un cas particulier. C'est en fait le résultat d'une contraction ou disons d'un raccourci sémantique, rendu possible par le contexte de la question.

Dans *je ne regarde que les films*, il faut entendre *les films* comme un sous-ensemble des programmes existants (les films, les débats, les séries, les reportages, etc.), et en ce sens c'est donc bien un programme dont on définit la catégorie. Pour mieux se le représenter, on peut le reformuler comme ça (même si c'est un peu maladroit) :

> « Je ne regarde que **les** programmes *qui sont des films*. »

C'est donc surtout l'antécédent présent dans la question (*Vous regardez beaucoup d'**émissions** à la télévision ?*) qui fait de *film* un programme défini.

Et en prenant un contexte neutre sans cet antécédent, comme :

> « Qu'est-ce que tu fais le soir quand tu t'ennuies ?
>
> - Je regarde les films. »

... serait choquant à l'oreille, on ne pourrait dire que *Je regarde **des** films*.

Pour conclure avec ton autre cas (les romans), on pourrait avoir :

> Et tu lis beaucoup ?
>
> Oui, mais je n'aime que **les** romans.

(J'ai un peu modifié la réponse pour montrer ce dont je parlais plus haut. Ici, on n'a même pas le choix, l'article indéfini serait inopiné.)

Comment: Merci ! C'est un peu subtil mais je pense que j'ai compris l'idée. Donc si la question était "Et tu lis beaucoup **de livres**?", je devrais répondre "Non, je ne lis que **les** romans" car romans sont un sous-ensemble - il y a des biographies, des livres techniques, des romans, etc. Dans ce cas, **romans** est un type de livres et donc est défini. Il y a beaucoup de détails que l'on doit faire attention quand on parle en français :) Merci !

Comment: @cldjr Oui, c'est bien ça, tu aurais alors les deux possibilités : *Non, je ne lis que **les/des** romans*.