# Quand utiliser "il y a les" vs "il y a des"?

Tags: articles

Je vois souvent les deux, laquelle est correcte? Par exemple:

> Il y a **des** gens
> Il y a **les** filles très belles

Is there an easy to use "rule of thumb" to remember what to use?

Comment: **Les** est l'article défini pluriel et **des** l'article indéfini pluriel. Une [question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/18776/358) à ce sujet sur l'emploi des articles définis et indéfinis au singulier (*le/la* vs *un/ une*) et les réponses à cette [question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/11108/358) pour compléter. [A basic lesson](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/articles/) about definite and indefinite articles in French.

Comment: "il y a les filles tres belles" is wrong. It would be better to say "Il y a des filles très belles" or much better "Il y a de très belles filles"

Comment: @Weedoze : not necessarily wrong. Consider the following sentences : « Il y a les filles très belles et il y a les autres. » or « Il y a les filles très belles d’un côté et les filles moches de l’autre. »

Comment: @Stéphane In your sentence it is correct but using only "Il y a les filles très belle." It means nothing, It is wrong

Comment: @Weedoze I agree.

Comment: Pourquoi pas "Il y a [ici] les filles très belles (sous-entendu : que nous avons vues ce matin)." même s'il est plus idiomatique de dire "Les jolies filles sont là." par exemple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know when use "les" or "des", you simply have to follow these grammar rules (same rules in english):

1. definite article/article défini : the/le, la, les : these articles are used when we know the person, animal or object we are talking about.
2. indefinite article/article indéfini : a, an, some, any/un, une, des : these articles are used when we know nothing about the person, animal or object we are talking about.

Also both phrases are corrects :

- "Il y a des gens"/there is people : it means you don't know anything at all about these people.
- "Il y a les filles"/there is the girls : it means you know these girls.
  *For example :* entering in a bar : "Cool, il y a les filles !" : you're happy, your gang composed by girl is her.

Hoping to help you

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt I think that it works in the following sentence for instance : "Viens chez Bastien ! Il y a les filles, Christophe, Vincent et Bastien, évidemment". However, the sentence from the OP ("il y a les filles très belles") is, I think, plain wrong.

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues Intéressant, sans doute une nuance dans l'usage ; _il y a les filles qui sont là_ ok, _les filles sont là_ ok, _évidemment qu'il y a des filles_ ok, _il y a les filles, évidemment, qui nous attendent de pied ferme_, ok., mais je peux pas digérer _il y a les filles, évidemment_ ou la variante avec _cool_. Merci !